# Unable to send text to Email field on Microsoft login page using Selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to figure out a way to automatically log in / enter text into a given text field on a particular web page. I've already don't this before, but this particular page isn't responding to anything I've thrown at it yet.

The default page load already has the auto-focus on the necessary text box. I'm currently using Python to write the Selenium code. My current script includes prior processes that lead to the page in question, where my current problem lies. Additionally, I've been running this code in a Google-Chrome browser, but with the user-agent selected to Edge - Mobile (but that probably won't matter here).

The website in question is the Microsoft login at [this link](https://login.live.com/login.srf?wa=wsignin1.0&rpsnv=13&ct=1522472835&rver=6.7.6631.0&wp=MBI&wreply=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.bing.com%2Fsecure%2FPassport.aspx%3Frequrl%3Dhttps%253a%252f%252fwww.bing.com%252fsearch%253fq%253dski%2526qs%253dn%2526form%253dQBRE%2526sp%253d-1%2526pq%253ds%2526sc%253d0-0%2526sk%253d%2526cvid%253d93C0EE27FBAA4F4586E4D80F72C2E2CC%2526wlexpsignin%253d1&lc=1033&id=264960&pcexp=false&CSRFToken=bbab580f-8f65-4ade-8c0c-a59f2d845e2d&aadredir=1).

The CSS/HTML of the text box in question:

```
<input type="email" name="loginfmt" id="i0116" maxlength="113" lang="en" class="form-control ltr_override" aria-describedby="usernameError loginHeader loginDescription" aria-required="true" data-bind="textInput: usernameTextbox.value,
                    hasFocusEx: usernameTextbox.focused,
                    placeholder: $placeholderText,
                    ariaLabel: tenantBranding.UserIdLabel || str['CT_PWD_STR_Username_AriaLabel'],
                    css: { 'has-error': usernameTextbox.error },
                    attr: inputAttributes" placeholder="Email, phone, or Skype" aria-label="Enter your email, phone, or Skype.">
```

The code I'm currently testing (which is basically three varied iterations of the same idea), after the given page loads:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id("i0116")
element.click()
element.clear() 
element.send_keys("wbhyatt3@gmail.com")
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(1)

element = driver.find_element_by_name("loginfmt") 
element.click()
element.clear()
element.send_keys("wbhyatt3@gmail.com")
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

time.sleep(1)

element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input.email")
element.click() 
element.clear()
element.send_keys("wbhyatt3@gmail.com") 
element.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

Unfortunately, trying to select the textbox via the input id, class, or name don't seem to be working. It should be worth noting that the page CSS I'm referencing for the text box includes an element "input" prior - I'm not sure if this will affect my current code. I'm fairly certain that either the send_keys aren't working, or perhaps the selection of the element, itself.

What makes the situation even more frustrating is that the page's default focus is on the textbox - so I don't even truly need to select the element, I just need to be able to enter text and submit/enter.

I've also tried targeting it as an iframe, but that hasn't seemed to help either.

Any ideas? Any and all help would be deeply appreciated. I am simply trying to find a way to enter text into the login box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enter an *EmailID* into the field with placeholder text as **Email, phone, or Skype** you can use the following code block :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://login.live.com/login.srf')
print("Page Title is : %s" %driver.title)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='form-control ltr_override' and @name='loginfmt']")
element.click()
element.clear()
element.send_keys("wbhyatt3@gmail.com")
```

Console Output :

```
Page Title is : Sign in to your Microsoft account
```

Snapshot :

[image: Microsoft]

Comment: Everything seems to be working. Thank you very much. Side question: say I was trying to do basically the same thing with the next page, which has password text box- how do I select the text box? I tried using your driver.find_element_by_xpath method but switched out the @class and @name's; however, nothing enters into the text field. Any thoughts?

Comment: Actually, it seems that I've got it! I realized that other parts of the code I was using that I hadn't posted were conflicting. Thanks again.