# Can't locate element on Microsoft Sign In page for Microsoft Forms

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I'm currently trying to locate Microsoft Sign In page's email input box by using xpath (others as well) but after many tries I still can't locate the correct element for it.

After copying the element from the page, this is the element given:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email, phone, or Skype" aria-required="true" spellcheck="false" autocomplete="off" data-bind="
                                    hasFocus: focus,
                                    textInput: email,
                                    attr: {'placeholder': config.text.emailPlaceHolder, 'aria-invalid': !error}">
```

And this is currently my python code:

```
login = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@class='form-control']")
login.send_keys(config.username)
login.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
```

I had tried multiple times but I still can't get the proper element to proceed. After entering https://forms.office.com/ I had successfully captured the sign in element but stuck at the next page.

Please NOTE that this is similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49584721/unable-to-send-text-to-email-field-on-microsoft-login-page-using-selenium) but is not the same as the page element is quite different. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Your target element is present in an iframe with `id` as `hrdIframe`. So you have to switch to the frame before interacting with the element.

```
driver.switch_to.frame('hrdIframe')
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='email']").send_keys(config.username)
```

Always make sure you switch back to default frame once you are done with the actions in iframe.